# Round the timestamp to hour in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

If we have timestamp in column like `'2018-01-01 01:35:00.000'`. I want to round off the timestamp to hour and get the value as `'2018-01-01 01:00:00.000'`.

Comment: This is not rounding off to me. It is truncate: 2018-01-01 01:35:00.000 -> 2018-01-01 01:00:00.000. Give me your expected value for 2018-01-01 01:22:00.000.

Comment: 2018-01-01 01:00:00.000

Answer (score 4):

So your question is not round but truncate the time format to hours.  The truncate function works only for date (Year, Month and Day) but not for time. For a workaround, you can use the snippet below:

```
date_format('2018-01-01 01:35:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-dd hh:00:00.000')
```

Result: 
2018-01-01 01:00:00.000

Comment: Additional info: in Spark 3 would be 'yyyy' in lower case :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **from_unixtime,unix_timestamp** functions to match your input data and create your required output format. in your case output format would be 
**yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00.000**

**Sample query:-**

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-01-01 01:35:00.000',"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:00:00.000');
    +--------------------------+--+
    |           _c0            |
    +--------------------------+--+
    | 2018-01-01 01:00:00.000  |
    +--------------------------+--+
```

(or)

2.if you just **want date** then change the output format to **yyyy-MM-dd**

```
hive>select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-01-01 01:35:00.000',"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"),'yyyy-MM-dd');
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2018-01-01  |
+-------------+--+
```

3.Extract **years and hours** --> output format is **yyyy hh**

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-01-01 01:35:00.000',"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"),'yyyy ss');
+----------+--+
|   _c0    |
+----------+--+
| 2018 00  |
+----------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

for the question asked :

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-01-01 01:35:00.000',"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00.000');
```

**To round off the time column to any granularity**

General Approach :

Hive-time-column-name : end_time

Hive-time-column-name-date-format : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Required-output-format : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

round-off-granularity : 15min

**Hive-query-command** :

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time-column-name-in-hive,"time-column-name-in-hive-date-format")-unix_timestamp(time-column-name-in-hive,"time-column-name-in-hive-date-format")%900 (because 15*60), 'output-date-format')
```

lets say end_time column value : 2019-11-29 08:23:27

so following command will convert end_time (ex. 2019-11-29 08:23:27 to 2019-11-29 08:15:00), given granularity is 15 min

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(end_time,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")-unix_timestamp(end_time,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")%900, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') from <table-name>;
```